# How to know when features from Windows Insider builds are publicly released?

Tags: windows-10, updates, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL.) New WSL features being released in Windows Insider builds. I'm **not** signed up for Insider builds - I want to limit myself to features that I can recommend my colleagues install and use without introducing any unexpected behavior or instability.

But I *am* excited to hear about when new features are released into public Windows 10, which I assume I'll get on my desktop from time to time as part of my normal scheduled Windows Updates.

How can I tell when new WSL features are released to the vanilla Windows 10 Pro that me and my colleagues are running?

**Update:** For example, is it likely that WSL updates will only happen during the two planned Windows 10 updates I read about here (http://www.pcworld.com/article/3104886/windows/two-major-windows-10-updates-scheduled-for-2017.html):

- Redstone 2, expected early 2017
- Redstone 3, expecterd summer or early fall 2017

Comment: Do you mean somehting like this?: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-info.aspx

Comment: Thanks @fernando.reyes. I could periodically check that page to see if new versions are released, and check the build numbers listed there against the build numbers in Windows Insider to see whether particular WSL features are released. That sounds like a lot of work for a process I'll be polling every so often. I appreciate the suggestion but am hoping for something that informs me when features go live, e.g. a good blog feed would do it. The WSL blogs I've found understandably focus on when features ship to Insider builds, rather than to the public builds.

Comment: New Windows 10 features in general will highlighted by Microsoft on their blog.  All blogs on Insider Builds apply to the next feature update.  Remember that WSL itself is a beta feature even in 1511 and 1607

Comment: Hey @Ramhoud, thanks for the info. When you say "microsoft's blog", it has a lot of posts with diverse content. I was hoping for something more focussed on WSL, or at least on the content of windows releases. When you mention "the next feature update", does that mean the two "Redstone" releases I mention in the question, or something else? Thanks for the "beta" reminder.

Comment: @JonathanHartley - Everything about WSL will be published to the Windows 10 blog.  Sadly, what you want, doesn't exist from Microsoft.  Canonical is responsible for the kernel updates while Microsoft is resonsible for everything else.